# Can't install a npm module with webpacker-react

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, webpack, webpacker

I would like to install react-dropzone in my project. 
I use react-rails project.
I had installed webpacker-react to use gem.
I installed react-dropzone via `npm install`, but i can't load it in my react components. (I suppose it's due to webpacker-react).
So, how to load modules installed via npm to my react components?

**component.jsx**

```
import Dropzone from 'react-dropzone'

class Main extends React.Component {

    onDrop(file) {

    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <div>
                    <Dropzone onDrop={this.onDrop().bind(this)}>
                        <p>To Fix</p>
                    </Dropzone>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

**package.json** (well installed)

```
"react-dropzone": "^3.13.3",
```

**Error message in firefox console:**

```
ReferenceError: require is not defined
in Debugger :
var _reactDropzone = require('react-dropzone');
```

**webpacker.yml**

```
default: &default
  source_path: app/javascript
  source_entry_path: packs
  public_output_path: packs

  extensions:
    - .coffee
    - .erb
    - .js
    - .jsx
    - .ts
    - .vue
    - .sass
    - .scss
    - .css
    - .png
    - .svg
    - .gif
    - .jpeg
    - .jpg

development:
  <<: *default

  dev_server:
    host: 0.0.0.0
    port: 8080
    https: false

test:
  <<: *default

  public_output_path: packs-test

production:
  <<: *default
```

**configuration.js**

```
//Common configuration for webpacker loaded from config/webpacker.yml

const { join, resolve } = require('path')
const { env } = require('process')
const { safeLoad } = require('js-yaml')
const { readFileSync } = require('fs')

const configPath = resolve('config', 'webpacker.yml')
const loadersDir = join(__dirname, 'loaders')
const settings = safeLoad(readFileSync(configPath), 'utf8')[env.NODE_ENV]

function removeOuterSlashes(string) {
  return string.replace(/^\/*/, '').replace(/\/*$/, '')
}

function formatPublicPath(host = '', path = '') {
  let formattedHost = removeOuterSlashes(host)
  if (formattedHost && !/^http/i.test(formattedHost)) {
    formattedHost = `//${formattedHost}`
  }
  const formattedPath = removeOuterSlashes(path)
  return `${formattedHost}/${formattedPath}/`
}

const output = {
  path: resolve('public', settings.public_output_path),
  publicPath: formatPublicPath(env.ASSET_HOST, settings.public_output_path)
}

module.exports = {
  settings,
  env,
  loadersDir,
  output
}
```

Comment: Please include your `webpack.config.js` for us.

Comment: I don't have the webpack.config.js because I use webpacker and not webpack. 
I suppose that configuration.js is the equivalent of webpack.config.js

Comment: Have you tried to change `import Dropzone from 'react-dropzone'` in your `component.jsx` to `var Dropzone = require("react-dropzone")` ?